# Migrate SharePoint 2010 Calendar Items to SharePoint Online (O365) with recurring meeting options

Tags: calendar, recurring-events, migrate

Our company is finally migrating from SharePoint 2010 to the new SharePoint Online/O365 solution.  Part of this is we need to take the calendars we had in SharePoint 2010 and duplicate them in the new environment.  This is easy enough for single meetings, but we are having problems with recurring meetings, since it's more than just a few items in a custom list.

Any ideas on how to Migrate Recurring Meetings from SharePoint 2010 to the latest SharePoint Online environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up migrating our calendars with a tool called ShareGate.  This seems to have worked.